# How much is VLIW power- and area-efficient then superscalar anyway?

Tags: computer-architecture

Most of texts say VLIW, which is lack of hardware to detect hazards and schedule the instructions. But I haven't see any evaluation about how much VLIW can save area(h/w complexity) and power compared to matching superscalar.

Any reliable source is welcomed. Please share with me.

Comment: What does "matching" mean? Statically scheduled VLIW and dynamic scheduling compare very differently for different kinds of code

Comment: @Harold I use the term "matching" for even performance when given enough ILP for both.